# print variable defined in action

Tags: java, jsp, struts

Can I print somehow string passed as an argument to a jsp? 
Let's assume I have action: 
package com.test;

```
 public class TestAction extends Action {

     String foo="bar";
   @Override
   public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
     //request.setParameter("foo", doo); // this does not work, I would like to achieve it. 
     return mapping.findForward("sql");
   }

 }
```

and jsp file:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <%@page contentType="text/html"%>
 <%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
 <%@page import="com.test.TestAction" %>
 <%= request.getParameter("foo") %>
```

I have in struts-config.xml defined:

```
 <action     
      name="loginForm"
      path="/login"
      scope="request"
      type="com.test.com.test.TestAction"
      validate="false">
          <forward name="sql" path="/index.jsp" />
 </action>
```

Can I do it?

Answer (score 4):

You need to change two things:

```
  request.setParameter("foo", doo);
```

should be

```
  request.setAttribute("foo", doo);
```

and

```
<%= request.getParameter("foo") %>
```

should be

```
<c:out value="${request.foo}"/>
```

partly for maintainability, and partly as protection against injection attacks ... unless you actually expect `doo` to contain valid (and safe) HTML tags.  (The use of `<c:out>` assumes that you have

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" %>
```

at the start of your JSP(s)).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `set/getAttribute` instead of `set/getParameter`?